# Why is self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a *UIViewController* that is pushed onto a *UINavigationController* and is currently displayed. When I go to start some asynchronous task inside the view controller, I can set **hidesBackButton** on self.navigationItem to **YES**, and the back button is hidden correctly.

As soon as the task is finished, and I set **hidesBackButton** back to **NO** (on the UI thread, I might add, I've made sure of this), nothing happens. The back button remains hidden.

Has anyone seen this before? What drives me especially crazy is that in my application (the same application), in a different *UINavigationController* hierarchy, the exact same code works correctly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling hidesBackButton = NO from a thread? All UI operations should be done on the main thread, otherwise they won't have any effect.

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread is used to shunt tasks over to the UI thread, correct?

Comment: But... your question explicitly states that you had made sure you were setting hidesBackButton to NO on the UI thread!

Answer (score 2):

i have not been able to replicate your problem on my machine. however, i faced a similar issue with tableviews even when i was updating my ui on the main thread. but calling setNeedsDisplay fixed that issue.

Can you try this and see if this works:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
```

I guess this should work, you need to do the same, BUT ON THE NAVIGATIONBAR instead. please let me know if this worked - as i cannot test my solution because i never get this problem :-)

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm, interesting - I will give that a try. It still bothers me that this works in one of my other UINavigationControllers, though, and doesn't work in a different UINavigationController. Why would one need to be redisplayed, while the other doesn't? :-/

Comment: haha - good question mate - i still havent figured out why my tableview display updates on my first view and does not on my second view ;-) i face the same problem with UIAlertViews too!!!

Comment: Haha, yeah, I've seen weird stuff like that too, *sigh*, the SDK is getting better, but it's not up to par, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forcing the view to refresh by calling setNeedsDisplay?
Maybe the OS is not picking up the changes instantly and you need to force it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the setHidesBackButton:animated: method instead?  Perhaps that has a slightly different behavior.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but it worries me that I'm doing something wrong instead in one of my UINavigationControllers, since it works in the other UINavigationController. Resorting to a different version of setHidesBackButton just seems like a band-aid.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I simply had to give a title to the view, as in:
self.navigationItem.title = @"Menu";

Marinus

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue recently. I tried literally everything I found in SO and other forums- nothing worked.

In my case there was a modally shown `UINavigationController` with a simple root controller which would push one of two view controllers (A and B) on top of the controller stack when the button A or B was pressed, respectively. Controller B was the one which was not supposed to show the back button. But still, sometimes it did, sometimes it didn't.

After hours of debugging, I managed to track it down. Controller A was a `UITableViewController`. Each time I selected a cell in this controller, the delegate would pop Controller A off the stack. BUT. I made use of a `UISearchDisplayController` as well. Turned out that popping the view while the search controller was still active messed up something in the navigation controller that made it impossible to hide the back button in Controller B afterwards (well, it eventually stayed hidden between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:` but then it always turned visible).

So the solution (rather workaround) was adding this line to where Controller A was dismissed:

```
controllerA.searchDisplayController.active = NO;

// ...
// [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this spares someone a couple of hours.