# backButton of NavigationController don't appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have already post this question but this time I post code. So I have a uiviewController, and in the viewDidLoad of this viewController I hide the backButton of the navigationController. After that, I push a new uiviewcontroller, and I set the backbutton to visible in the viewDidLoad, but the backbutton is still hidden...

Implementation of the first uiviewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"page2page2page2page2page2";

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
}

-(IBAction)click
{
    page3 *controller = [[page3 alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [page3 release];
}
```

Implementation of the  page 3

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"page3";
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = FALSE;

}
```

and the page3 has no backbutton, but the space is created for the button, because the tile "page 3" is on the right and not in the center... all this happen with the ios 4.2

thx

Comment: try it in viewwillappear and viewwilldisapper of page 2

Comment: I tried but it does not work...

Comment: The similar post, I suspect here is the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708033/why-is-self-navigationitem-hidesbackbutton-not-working/712918#712918

Comment: possible duplicate of [back button don't appear in navigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281063/back-button-dont-appear-in-navigationcontroller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same behaviour and I must say I find it quite strange. I can't say why it doesn't work but as a workaround you can do:

In page2:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

And in page3:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

And remove the calls to `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = ...` in both controllers.

Comment: thx for the solution Robert, it's not perfect but it's work! Your problem happen with the ios 4.2 also?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the above workarounds seemed to work for me. However when the third view was being displayed, i could see the button blink for a moment. So I suspected the problem (bug) has to do with the animation

When change animated to NO on the pushViewController the problem went away

```
- (IBAction)btnNext:(id)sender {

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: AAAARRRGGGHHH. This works for me. But I wanted animation on. I'm wondering why animation could make such a difference.

Answer (score 2):

My trick is setting setNavigationBarHidden to YES and immediately NO.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

So as this the backButton not be animated but it's really work and my manager have not notice it ;P

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem running iOS 4.2. The back button would refuse to appear. Upon autoroating to landscape, it then appears. My solution was to do the following - This fixed the problem...or should we say its a workaround ;)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}
```