# iPhone - UINavigationItem - hiding back button

Tags: iphone, uinavigationitem

I'm stumped. I'm using a UINavigationController and on one view I'm trying to hide the back button. But when I do that it hides the back button on the next level of views also.

In `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` I have:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```

And in `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` I have:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO];
```

This just makes the back button appear just before it leaves (which seems like that is the correct functionality of that call). Therefore I tired to put

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO];
```

in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` of the next view, and that still doesn't work.

This is a little confusing since `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is a reference of what that view's back button will be when it is the view just under the top view ([ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem)). But `self.navigationItem.hidesBackbutton` is whether the back button is shown when it is the top view ([ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/hidesBackButton)). So does anyone have any idea why it would hide the back button of the next view?

Another strange thing is it works when I go another view down. For a more visual representation, lets say I have the following views:

```
A > B > C > D
```

B is the view I'm concerned about. I want to hide the back button which would go to A. When I do that it hides the back button on C also. But if I do down to D, the back button shows up and then everything acts as it "should." That is, I can go back to C, then Back to B. B has it's back button hidden and if I go back into C the back button shows up like it should.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of bug regarding the hiding and showing of the back button when dealing with a `UINavigationController`. A similar problem to yours is [backButton of NavigationController don't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315952/backbutton-of-navigationcontroller-dont-appear/4318839#4318839).

I did some testing regarding this and while I don't have an explanation here are some suggestions that might help you.

- Only make calls to `setHidesBackButton:animated:` in `viewDidAppear:` and *not* in `viewWillAppear:`
- Don't use `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Putting it in viewDidAppear helped. Any way to stop it from flashing for a split second?

Answer (score 4):

To get by this stupid bug, I did not implement setHidesBackButton at all, but in viewDidLoad I put the following:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I experienced the exact same issue and your workaround helps!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know that hiding the back button doesn't prevent a user from clicking on it?

To prevent a click, you have to set it as nil.

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtomItem = nil;
```

Then you could create a new back button in "B"'s `viewWillAppear` method.